# Using the same ArrayList over different classes

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I'm quite new to this, mostly taught myself so any advice would help me. I've had a stab at this and now it seems like I'm going in circles...

So I've made a GUI using the netbeans GUI builder... I have a main menu, and I want to be able to modify an arraylist from any frame...

I have an employee object that I want to go in an ArrayList that I can access from any class file. I looked around for some help on this site but got stuck eventually trying to figure out how to apply it to my own.

```
public class EmployeesDATA {
private ArrayList<Employee> EmployeesDATA;
Main m; //not so sure what this is meant to do 

public EmployeesDATA(Main m) {

    EmployeesDATA = new ArrayList<>();
    this.m = m; 
 }

 public ArrayList<Employee> getList() {
   return EmployeesDATA;
 }

 public void addEmployee(Employee e){
    EmployeesDATA.add(e);
 }
 }
```

This is where I started getting really confused... Ended up making this class trying to emulate someones else advice lol.

```
public class Main {
     public static EmployeesDATA Employees;

public Main() {
//test employee    
Employee TestObject = new Employee("Jeff","b",1);

//make a new list using this class file only.
Employees = new EmployeesDATA(this);

//add a employee to the list.
Employees.addEmployee(TestObject);
}//end method

public void addEmployeeMainList(Employee e) {
    Employees.addEmployee(e);
    System.out.println("added employee.");
 }
```

I think what I'm trying to get at is an ArrayList that is only created once and then called elsewhere. My very early attempts were creating new ArrayLists and losing the old data.

Next is my MainMenu class which is where the GUI is created. The main method is in here but I haven't touched it as it has a lot of other generated stuff in it already:

```
public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {  

private EmployeesDATA Employees; 

public MainMenu() {
    initComponents(); //generated

System.out.println(Main.Employees.getList().get(0).employeeFirstName + "test 1"); // I seem to crash out here...
//pretty confused, I can call the Main class but I can't get the Employees.addEmployeeMainList method which is where I wanted to try to keep it protected... Any help there?

 //eventually I will move on to assigning stuff to my GUI items like this:
 //Populate Combo Box with Employees.
    for(int x = 0; x < Employees.size(); x++){
    SelectEmployeeComboBox.addItem(Employees.get(x).employeeFirstName);
    }}
```

I'm really just confusing myself at this point, I'm pretty sure there is a much simpler way of doing this that is eluding me.
Any pointers even if it doesn't solve the problem at hand appreciated. Here to learn :).

Comment: You could try to use an interface in order to reduce coupling. Take a look at the [mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) for example.

Comment: Too much code, this is annoying to read, think about the readers and clarifiy your point consiely

Comment: Sure I'll cut it down... 1min...

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish here. Also I suggest you use the java convention of beginning variable names with lower case, this makes it immediately distinguishable from a class.

Comment: Jyr - had a look at the background and I understand the benefits now. Probably will try it on a different project and learn how to do it that way.

Comment: Atuos - Yeah, I was very confused so wasn't exactly sure what to ask for. I'll take you up on the lower case variable convention though, ty

Comment: No problem. It might look daunting at first, but once you understand the principle it's relatively easy. In my answer I tried to explain such a principle in a very basic way (I think). Also, when you want to address people in the comments, don't forget to add `@` (e.g. @Jyr), this way the person you address will get a notification.

Comment: @Jyr Learning something new all the time :) cheers buddy, I'll have a good look. Seems it will be super useful when programs get way more complex than this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the `Main` class - it makes no sense at all, and try this

```
public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {  

private EmployeesDATA employees = new EmployeesDATA(); 

public MainMenu() {
    initComponents(); //generated

    Employee testObject = new Employee("Jeff","b",1);
    employees.addEmployee(testObject);
    System.out.println(employees.getList().get(0).employeeFirstName + "test 1"); 

    for(int x = 0; x < Employees.size(); x++){
    SelectEmployeeComboBox.addItem(Employees.get(x).employeeFirstName);
}}
```

Comment: Youre having to dig into the implementation of EmployeesDATA class with all those dots just to get one employee; I'd wrap the `.get(int)` in a method so you don't have to reach into the internal list.

Comment: I had a pop at this one, its works as you have written inside the main menu class. If I want to use it in a different GUI frame then I had to whack 'Static' in front of the arraylist, the method and the Test Employee object... is this bad convention? it works at least.

Comment: It is bad convention and sticking your data inside a GUI component is bad design.

Comment: @DavidSoroko Ok. Completing overhauling it then, taking into account what others have said as well. I've moved everything out of the GUI files, made a lot of methods to handle all of the dots... Seems to be making progress and I am a lot happier now. I'd rather have to take a step back and redo something right than learn it the wrong way... Accepting this answer ty.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what do u want to do but if you want to hold all your data in a list and be able to do so from anywhere and control what can be done

```
 class Data{
    private data(){};

        private static final ArrayList<Employee> elist =new ArrayList<Employee>();

        public static void add(Employee e){
          elist.add(e)
         }
      //search..
      //get a copy of list..
     //watever..
    }
```

From anywhere you can call Data.add(e)

Comment: Can you please explain why? Does this violate encapsulation in any way?

Comment: Mutable global state makes it difficult to figure out how a program works. It can be difficult to find where in the code the list is being modified, as it could be used anywhere at all. In essence, it encourages highly-coupled spaghetti code. The alternative is to just pass the the list to the objects that need it. It becomes immediately clear what depends on what and what is modifying the list.

Comment: The list is private static final .... The list cannot be modified from anywhere else but methods of this class only.

Comment: The list can be modified from anywhere at all by using the class methods.

Comment: The point where this structural modification happens is in this class and not scattered everywhere.If this class is not public it will not be accessible from everywhere but yes got your point..thanks